# Variable in Cabal (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, cabal

I am trying to write a package in Haskell.  This package contains a library and an executable.  I am specifying this in the Cabal file.  There are three basic components of the library:

1) There are the exposed modules of the library

2) There are internal build-dependencies that should not be exported as part of the library

3) There are external build-dependencies.

There is a bit of overlap in the Cabal file.  For the library I write:

exposed-modules: The List of Exposed Modules

other-modules: The List of other modules

build-depends: The List of build dependencies

Then for the executable
other-modules: The list of exposed modules and other modules are needed in the executable
build-depends: The list of build dependencies

What would be nice is if Cabal lets me have a variable.

V1 = List exposed modules

V2 = List other modules

V3 = List build dependencies

Then in the executable, for example, I could do

other-modules: V1,V2

build-depends: V3

Alternatively, I would take a recommendation for a better way to use the Cabal system!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible yet. I think we have a feature request for something like this on the issue tracker somewhere. Note, however, that your executable can depend on the library defined in the same `.cabal` file, so you don't have to share `exposed-modules` and `other-modules`:

```
Name: some-package
Version: 0.1
[...]

Library
    build-depends: some-dependency >= 1.0, ...        
    exposed-modules: A, B, C
    other-modules: C, D, E
    [...]

Executable some-exe
    main-is: SomeExe.hs
    build-depends: some-package == 0.1
```

For a real-world example, see [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/ghc-parmake/0.1.6/ghc-parmake.cabal).

Comment: Thank you!  The dependency on the same package solves my problem.